Making background-color "slide" nicely between table cells using pure CSS?
I've got a table where some of each row's cells contain labels and radio buttons.
The active cell's label is given a background color to identify it as active.
If the user changes the active cell, I would like the background color to "slide" from the currently-active cell into the newly-selected cell.
I've got it kind-of working using pseudo-elements and transform: translateX(...); with this code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/moj791dh/


/* Apply sliding effect */
td {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* First column always exits right */
td:first-of-type label::before {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

/* Last column always exits left */
td:last-of-type label::before {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

/* Selected label */
label:has(input[type="radio"]:checked)::before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

/* Labels after the selected label always exit left */
td:has(input[type="radio"]:checked) ~ td label::before {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 1
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 2
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 3
      </label>
    </td>
    <td data-column-type="other">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 4
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 5
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



You'll see it works quite nicely if you click the cells sequentially. It looks nice and smooth and it changes direction appropriately.
However if you click around more widely (e.g. cell #1 to cell #5) then it starts to look ugly.
Each row of the table should be able to have its own "sliding" background.
Is there a way to achieve this in pure CSS, ideally without any extra HTML elements? I feel like there should be especially with the recent advances with the @property rule etc. but I can't figure it out!

Maybe it's not what your eyes were expecting to see, but I think this is a very cool and original effect on its own!

A solution using anchor positioning and :has(). Not yet ready for production use but keep it for a near future.
Use chrome to test the below:


tr {
  position: relative;
}
tr::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  position-anchor: --label;
  inset: anchor(top) anchor(right) anchor(bottom) anchor(left);
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

td:has(input:checked) {
  anchor-name: --label;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 1
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 2
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        a longer option 
      </label>
    </td>
    <td data-column-type="other">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Option 4
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Op 5
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        Option 1
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        Option 2
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        a longer option 
      </label>
    </td>
    <td data-column-type="other">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        Option 4
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        Op 5
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




That's very cool but I assume this won't work as intended for a table with multiple rows, would it? At least not without specifying a different anchor for every row. It would shift the background between the rows (appearing to move vertically). Each row should be independent and the sliding should only be "horizontal". I'll update my question to make that clear.

@WackGet - You could supply the row name via a custom property from the HTML though. You're already providing the radio group name for each row in the HTML, so it's not much of an extension to put style="--row-name:--row1", style="--row-name:--row2" etc on each tr. Like this: https://jsbin.com/lexuruvuke/edit?html,css,output

@Alohci Thanks, that's perfect (at least as soon as it becomes widely adopted). Cheers!

@WackGet see the update, we can scope anchor using position: relative and move the pseudo to the tr instead

@Alohci not really needed, we can scope the anchor per row (see edits)

Thanks for clarifying that, @TemaniAfif. I thought I'd tried that but clearly my test must have been incorrect. I love this answer. A terrific example of what anchor positioning can do.

@TemaniAfif Awesome, thanks a lot. Do you think there would have been another pure CSS solution without using anchor positioning? (I don't mind waiting for full adoption but just curious if there's another way to achieve this in Firefox etc.)
